# MODX Как сделать фильтрацию по TV полям?

Tags: modx, revo

не подскажите как правильно написать такой запрос в pdoResources

```
Лифт: пассажирский
Помещение: 1
Грузоподъёмность: от 300 до 800
Скорость: от 3 до 5

[[!pdoResources?
  &tpl=`product-tpl`
  &parents=`2`
  &includeTVs=`lift,type_room,load_capacity,speed`
  &tvFilters=`lift == пассажирский,
         type_room == 1,
         load_capacity >= 300,
         load_capacity =< 800,
         speed >= 3,
         speed =< 5`
]]
```

И так пробовал

```
[[!pdoResources?
  &tpl=`product-tpl`
  &parents=`2`
  &includeTVs=`lift,type_room,load_capacity,speed`
  &where=`{
    "lift":"пассажирский",
    "type_room": 1,
    "load_capacity:IN":[300,800],
    "speed:IN":[3,5]
    }`
]]
```

Тут вроде это условие не срабатывает "load_capacity:IN":[300,800]

Может есть у кого нибудь пример фильтрации (поля select и поле ОТ и ДО интересуют)?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
&where=`{
"lift:=":"пассажирский",
"AND:type_room:=":"1",
"AND:load_capacity:>=":"300",
"AND:load_capacity:<=":"800",
"AND:speed:>=":"3",
"AND:speed:<=":"5"
}`
```

Синтаксис (на английском):
https://docs.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.where

Небольшое описание (на русском):
http://mudrenizm.ru/index.php?id=120